# SQL Server 2008 Version Problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, restore, database-restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restore Problem SQL Server Version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128578/restore-problem-sql-server-version)

I have recently upgraded to SQL Server 2008 express from SQL Server 2005 express.

But when I tried to run following command on SQL Server 2008 Query window

```
Select @@Version
```

I am getting following output:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -
>   9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86) May 26 2009 14:24:20 Copyright (c) 1988-2005
>   Microsoft Corporation Express Edition
>   on Windows NT 6.0 (Build 6002: Service
>   Pack 2)

Can anyone please tell me why there is a version difference?

Because of this versioning problem I am getting restore errors as follows:

> Restore failed for Server
>        An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>        The media family on device 'C:\go4sharepoint_1384_8481.bak' is
>   incorrectly formed. SQL Server cannot
>   process this media family. RESTORE
>   HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3241)
>        For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=09.00.4053&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=3241&LinkId=20476