# make .bak file compatible to other mssql version

Tags: sql-server, database-restore

client has .bak file created with another mssql version. I am facing compatibility issue on my own mssql version to restore the back up. I want to know if there is anyway to make the .bak file compatible to my version (like converting online)

Comment: No, if your client has a version of SqlServer greater than yours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128578/restore-problem-sql-server-version?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

no. You and your client must use the same SQL Server version if you want to exchange backups.

Depending on what your role is (developer, admin etc) the very idea of exchanging backup files may be wrong. Developers do not need a backup from the client nor do they deliver database binaries, but instead they deliver deployment scripts.